# Grails 4: Micronaut fails with NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PreDestroy

Tags: grails, micronaut, grails-4

I migrated a Grails 3.3.10 application to Grails 4.0.0, moving from Java 8 to OpenJDK 11. After some work to make the tests and application run on my development environment ( a windows 10 machine ), I packaged my executable war in a docker `adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine`. The docker's entrypoint just runs the app:

```
java <some options> -jar /app/application.war
```

The docker when run however gives an error when initializing Micronaut:

> java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: Error loading service
>   [org.grails.databinding.converters.$DefaultConvertersConfigurationDefinitionClass]:
>   javax/annotation/PreDestroy
>
> at io.micronaut.core.io.service.DefaultServiceDefinition.lambda$load$0(DefaultServiceDefinition.java:71)
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PreDestroy
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PreDestroy

I tried to add `compile 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'` in my gradle dependencies, without success.

What's missing to make my application run?

Comment: "What's missing to make my application run?" - Without seeing the project it is hard to say.  I can't reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java 11 no longer ships with some of the javax libraries.

Following the instruction from https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-11-migration-guide/#Migrating-From-Java-8-To-Java-11 solved the issue.